# Can I change facebook timeline actions after submission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I am in the process of adding timeline integration in an app by defining a couple custom actions, but there is a chance that we may change these later on (adding optional parameters, changing the box visualization, wording etc).

Is this possible to do *after* we have submitted the actions for approval, and after they are eventually approved? I expect them to need to go through approval again but I am not sure.

What happens to already published actions?
What happens during the eventual re-approval process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course your actions have to go through approval again if you change them.

For existing and approved actions, those should stay in place as they are when you change them and submit them for approval again, they will show their “old” behavior until the changes are approved.